# How to run evaluating expression in MySQL and update column accordingly?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
tweets                                     stocks
-------------------------------------      -----------------------------
id stock_id nyse_date   class quality      stock_id _date         return
-------------------------------------      -----------------------------
1  1        2011-03-12  3                  1        2011-03-12    0.44
2  1        2011-03-12  1                  1        2011-03-15    0.17
3  1        2011-03-15  2                  2        2011-03-15   -0.03
4  2        2011-03-15  2
5  2        2011-03-16  1
```

I need to evaluate the following expression and fill in the result in the `quality` column by using solely SQL:

```
IF (class_value of tweet/return on that day) > 0 THEN quality = 1 ELSE 0
```

With class_value being:

```
IF class = 1 THEN class_value =  0
IF class = 2 THEN class_value =  1
IF class = 3 THEN class_value = -1
```

For each tweet, I need to (obviously) take the stock return of that date. During the weekend, for exapmple at `2011-03-16`, there is no stock data available. In that case, `quality` should default to 0 as well (and not return an error). So let's do this manually for the 4 tweets in the example:

```
id  class  class_value  return  class_value/return  quality
-----------------------------------------------------------
1   3      -1            0.44   -1/0.44  =  -2.27   0
2   1       0            0.44    0/0.44  =   0      0
3   2       1            0.17    1/0.17  =   5.88   1
4   2       1           -0.03    1/-0.03 = -33.33   0
5   1       0            n/a                        0
```

So the end result of the query then would be an updated `tweets` table:

```
tweets                               
-------------------------------------
id stock_id nyse_date   class quality
-------------------------------------
1  1        2011-03-12  3     0
2  1        2011-03-12  1     0
3  1        2011-03-15  2     1
4  2        2011-03-15  2     0
5  2        2011-03-16  1     0
```

I don't know how to put all this into a query. I now have this, but it only selects the class and return but doesn't set `class_value` or implement the expression.

```
UPDATE tweets SET quality = (
  SELECT t.class, s.return FROM tweets t 
  LEFT JOIN stocks s ON t.nyse_date = s._date
)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update tweets
   set quality = ifnull(case tweets.class
                             when 1 then 0
                             when 2 then 1
                             when 3 then -1
                        end
                 -- If there is no match, subquery will evaluate to null
                 -- Division will also evaluate to null
                      / (select `return`
                           from stocks
                          where tweets.nyse_date = stocks._date
                            and tweets.stock_id = stocks.stock_id
                        )
                 -- If there was no match, quality = 0
                      , 0)
                 -- Shortcut to set 1 if condition is satisfied
                 -- If there is an error try encapsulating
                 -- whole expression into case when (ex) then 1 else 0 end
                      > 0
```

I wanted to test this, as I'm not working with MySql, but my favourite Sql Fiddle is down at the moment.

Comment: Thanks, SQLFiddle is still down so I made a copy of my database for testing. I had to backquote `return` but then it ran. However, it kept on running untill it timed out after 20 mins. How can I `LIMIT` this query to perform the operation in batches? I tried '[...] > 0 LIMIT 0, 1000' but I then get an error: `check for the right syntax to use near '1000'`

Comment: @Pr0no I'm often creating a loop and updating `where id between @lastID and @lastID - 10000`, and then set @lastID = @lastID - 10000. I don't know, however, how to do it in MySql. On the other hand, is it performing well if you convert it to select query? If not, an index on (stock_id, _date) will probably help.

Comment: a simple `BETWEEN x AND y` at the end of the query fixed it for me. Still wondering why `LIMIT` gave an error, though but that's besides this issue. Thanks :-) Here's some karma.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović sorry about that - SQL Fiddle is back now!

Comment: @JakeFeasel Nothing to be sorry about. Your site is a precious gift to our community.